# Simple diff/patch script for sorted unique file

Tags: shell, sorting, text-files, unique, patch

How could I write a simple diff resp. patch script for applying additions and deletions to a list of lines in a file?

This could be a original file (it is sorted and each line is unique):

```
a
b
d
```

a simple patch file could look like this (or somehow as simple):

```
+ c
+ e
- b
```

The resulting file should look like (or in any other order, since `sort` could be applied anyways):

```
a
c
d
e
```

The normal patch formats can not be used since they include context, which might alter in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash alternatives that read input files only once:

To generate patch you can:

```
comm -3 a.txt b.txt | sed 's/^\t/+ /;t;s/^/- /'
```

Because `comm` delimeters outputs from different files using tab, we can use that tab to detect if line should be added or removed.

To apply patch you can:

```
{ <patch.txt tee >(grep '^+ ' | cut -c3- >&5) |
grep '^- ' | cut -c3- | comm -13 - a.txt; } 5> >(cat)
```

The `tee` splits the input, that is the patch file, into two streams. The first part has `+` filtered and is outputted to file descriptor `5`. The file descriptor `5` is opened to just `>(cat)` so it is just outputted on stdout. The second part has the minus `-` filtered and it is joined with `a.txt` and outputted. Because output should be line buffered, it should work.

Comment: Cool B-) just adding `| sort -u` even gives a sorted file after applying the patch.

Answer (score 1):

A shell solution using `comm`, `awk`, and `grep` to apply such a patch would be:

```
A=a.txt B=b.txt P=patch.txt; { grep '^-' $P | cut -c 3- | comm -23 $A - ; grep '^+' $P | cut -c 3- } | sort -u > $B
```

to generate the patch file would be:

```
A=a.txt B=b.txt P=patch.txt; { comm -13 $A $B | awk '{print "+ " $0}' ; comm -23 $A $B | awk '{print "- " $0}' } > $P
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody could give me an answer, I've created a small python script, which does exactly this job. https://github.com/white-gecko/simplepatch

To apply such a patch call it with (where `outfile.txt` is generated)

```
./simplepatch.py -m patch -i infile.txt -p patchfile.txt -o outfile.txt
```

To generate a patch/diff call it with (where `patchfile.txt` is generated)

```
./simplepatch.py -m diff -i infile.txt -o outfile.txt -p patchfile.txt
```